# Nonempty intersection between approximate point spectrum and residual spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

On the Wikipedia page on "Spectrum (functional analysis)", it is mentioned that the approximate point spectrum and residual spectrum are not necessarily disjoint. Is there a straightforward example to illustrate this? I can't come up with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $X$ is a Banach space and $A$ is a bounded linear operator on $X$. $\lambda$ is in the point spectrum iff $\mathcal{N}(A-\lambda I) \ne \{0\}$. $\lambda$ is in the continuous spectrum iff $\mathcal{N}(A-\lambda I)=\{0\}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{R}(A-\lambda I)}=X$. Everything else is the residual spectrum.

You want $\lambda$ to be in the residual spectrum and in approximate point spectrum. So, $\mathcal{N}(A-\lambda I)=\{0\}$ is required, $\overline{\mathcal{R}(A-\lambda I)}\ne X$ is required, and there must exist a sequence of unit vectors $\{ x_n \}$ such that $(A-\lambda I)x_n \rightarrow 0$. Let $X=\ell^2$ and define
$$
            A(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots) = (0,x_1,\frac{1}{2}x_2,\frac{1}{3}x_3,\cdots).
$$
Clearly $\mathcal{N}(A)=\{0\}$, $(1,0,0,0,\cdots)\in\mathcal{R}(A)^{\perp}$, and $\{(1,0,0,\cdots),(0,1,0,\cdots),(0,0,1,\cdots),\cdots\}$ is a sequence of unit vectors whose images under $A$ converge in norm to $0$.